# Failed building wheel for pybgpstream

Tags: python

Hi Guys when I Try to install pybgpstream Using following command it gives me error. Please Help me out.

`!pip install pybgpstream`

Error:
Collecting pybgpstream
Using cached pybgpstream-2.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pybgpstream) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from python-dateutil->pybgpstream) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pybgpstream
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Building wheel for pybgpstream (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pybgpstream
Running setup.py clean for pybgpstream
Failed to build pybgpstream
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pybgpstream, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I install the wheel again but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you install `libBGPStream` before running the `pip install pybgpstream`. Else the wheel will fail when building.

Instructions for installation on multiple operating systems can be found: https://bgpstream.caida.org/docs/install/bgpstream

Comment: Same error 

 pip install pybgpstream
Collecting pybgpstream
  Using cached pybgpstream-2.0.2.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /home/saqib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pybgpstream) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil->pybgpstream) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pybgpstream
  Building wheel for pybgpstream (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.